# How to convert a numpy array to regular python list?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, nltk

So I am taking input from a csv file using pandas and performing tokenization on it using nltk. However I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    word = nltk.word_tokenize(words)
  File "/home/codelife/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 109, in word_tokenize
    return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "/home/codelife/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 94, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "/home/codelife/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1237, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "/home/codelife/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1285, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "/home/codelife/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1276, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "/home/codelife/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1276, in <listcomp>
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "/home/codelife/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1316, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "/home/codelife/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 310, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "/home/codelife/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1289, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

The following is the code:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import nltk     #for cleaning and stop wrds removal
import pandas as pd     #csv
import numpy

data = pd.read_csv("Sample.csv", usecols=[0])   #reading from csv file
num_rows = data.shape[0]
#print(questions)

# cleaning the data 

count_nan = data.isnull().sum() #counting no of null elements   
count_without_nan = count_nan[count_nan==0] #no of not null elements
data = data[count_without_nan.keys()]   # removing null columns

data_mat = data.as_matrix(columns= None) #converting to numpy matrix
print(data_mat)
for question in data_mat:
    words = question.tolist()
    word = nltk.word_tokenize(words)
    print(word)
```

I assumed it is because I am using a numpy array. How do I convert it to a regular python list?

Comment: No, it's because `nltk.word_tokenize` `expected string or bytes-like object`, as the error indicates. It would not help to convert to a `list`, which you've already done successfully anyway. I needs a *string*.

Comment: Look at `words`, or a portion of it.  Make sure you understand what it is and what it contains.

Comment: [`df.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is your friend =)

Answer (score 0):

The nltk's `word_tokenize()` function needs to get a single string. It will return a list of the tokens it contains. To apply it to an entire Python list, numpy array or pandas dataframe, you need iterate in Python (loop or comprehension) or use a numpy or pandas `apply*` method. For example, if `words` is an `np.array`, you can use the following comprehension to iterate over it.

```
sentences = [ nltk.word_tokenize(string) for string in words ]
```

If words is something else, you'll need to adapt the code or show us what it looks like in your question.